# How to disable limit of pattern attempts to unlock Android 2.1 device?

Tags: lock-screens

My unlock pattern is long and secure.

I don't want to wait for 30 seconds when I try to enter it inaccurately (it is tricky), also I don't want it to be blocked after 20 tries.

How to make it to accept patterns ad infinum? (I have the root access)

- Tried NoLock - it disabled the screen completely.
- Tried SkipLock - it behaves the same as standard pattern screen.

Are there applications for alternative locking? Mat be there is one where you enter digits instead of patterns (without attempt counter, of course).

Ideal lock screen for me: 16 buttons (plus "Emergency call") which I press without any indication. When the password occurred as substring the device is unlocked. Example: password: "59B13F", I press: "59159595B13F**59B13F** and it is unlocked. Without even the need for erasing mistyped password, can just type and re-type fast and carelessly.

Comment: What phone do you have and are you using the built-in lockscreen? The pattern lock on my 2.2 Galaxy S does not have a timeout, and I don't think it blocks either.

Comment: Mine has both. Built-in lockscreen from stock 2.1 from Motorola Milestone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you may consider an AppLock program.  It doesn't lock your phone, but it may provide the same purpose by locking any apps you want.  For the particular app I use, [Smart App Protector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sp.protector), (my version is from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004WM0AH0)) you can configure it to have unlimited retries (which is the default), and you can configure it to use a pattern or pin.  You can configure the relock delays as well, so you aren't entering in a pin or pattern every single time you open a program.

Comment: Remoted usual lock pattern and added almost all apps to Smart App Protector. Little question: how to enable emergency "112" dialler?

Comment: Hmm, good question.  I played around with my phone.  When I "lock" my phone, I find that I'm able to still use my direct dial shortcuts that I created in my launcher.  Can you create direct dial shortcuts on yours (long press on blank area of launcher screen, select Shortcut -> Direct Dial -> Select contact).  So if you add your emergency number of whatever, you can still call.

Comment: Have you actually tried it yourself? It can call contacts directly, including numbers like "000", but it can't call '112', it adds it like usual, but it does nothing when I click it. Also I want some confirmation before actually calling 112.

Comment: @Vi0, I was able to use direct dial for a normal number, but I haven't tried it for an emergency number (911 for U.S.)

Comment: I also tried number of 112/sos/emergency widgets. They either call up Phone (and show Smart App Protector screen) application or tries a direct call and silently fails (like a that shortcut thing).

Comment: you may try it. If it actually start calling you can quickly press "End call" before it actually brings up the call. May be direct calls to 112/911 was possible in earlier Androids?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Lockbot Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jackdoit.lockbot) - it has support for Pattern Lock or PIN entry. But on Eclair devices, it doesn't always work 100%. YMMV.

Also supports different themes and locking methods.

Answer (score -3):

PhoneLocator Pro
Has wipe after a number of unsuccessful attempts.
Lock device after 1 min/2 minutes.....

Comment: I'm looking for the reverse. Don't "punish" user no matter how much attempts. Just allow enter it again and again without delays.